# Where did the infinity sign come from and what exactly does it mean?

Tags: calculus

I know infinity means "forever" , but I don't understand where it came from who discovered it and decided what it meant.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_symbol) might help.

Comment: See also the post : [Where did John Wallis get the idea for $\infty$ ?](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/where-did-john-wallis-get-the-idea-for-infty)

Comment: Your title seems to suggest you want to know how the notation (symbol) came about, but the body of the questions is asking something different.